# Generating the json error message if the validation fails on the filds

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a form and i am submitting it using ajax call.I am using jsr 303 bean validation to validate the form fields.Now i am able to validate the fields but when any validation error comes then it should give the json error message other wise it is going to generate the report in the respective type.My big problem is how to generate the json error message if validation fails.My code in controller class is as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "pdf", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })

    public ModelAndView generatePdfReport(@ModelAttribute("reports") @Valid ReportsCommand model, BindingResult result, ModelAndView modelAndView,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Error in call type value123");

           // return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("../pages/report/main.jsp?module=report&page=fluctuations"));
            throw new BindException(result);
        } 
        else {
          .....
           return modelAndView;
           }
          }
```

and in my model class the below field i am validating

```
@Size(min = 2, max = 3, message = "calltype must between 2 to 3 Characters.")
    private String callType;
```

If result.hasErrors is true then i want to generate the json error message.How can i do this...

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried such thing with JSON. I don't know about that muchs. But you need to do some modifications in your controller method.
Like,

Change the return type to `void` instead of `ModelAndView`.
In method signature add one more parameter as  `HttpServletResponse response`.
And then you need to write the error data using `response.getWriter().write(//something here);`.

And in the ajax response you can get the string error message you have passed from controller.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You case is not simple. Every method defined in a controller may only return one type of view.

For exemple, if you want to return a json response, the controller's method needs to have the @ResponseBody annotation.

```
  public @ResponseBody Report generatePdfReport(@ModelAttribute("reports") @Valid ReportsCommand model, BindingResult result, ModelAndView modelAndView, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception { 
    return new Report();
  }
```

If you want to foward the response to a view where the validation result will be displayed, you'll have to use a ModelAndView return type like you did.

You won't be able to use two different response type for the same controller method. I sugess to break down the validation and the report generation in two distinct step.

Good luck !